# How to change labels from PCA using PRcomp to sample names

Tags: r, pca

I am trying to label a PCA biplot with sample names rather then the standard numbers. I am using the codes:

```
PRCOMP1 <- prcomp(~ Max + Min + Range + Average + P10 + P20 + 
P50 + P100 +  D10 + D20 + D50 + D100 + D500, 
data = turbidity, 
na.action = na.omit, 
scale = TRUE

biplot(PRCOMP1, cex = 0.8, choices=c(1,2))
```

which provides the below plot - does any know I can label the points with a column labelled Sample in my datasheet.

Also is there a easy way to change the colour of the arrows? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would name the rows of your input data with the value of the Sample column:

```
row.names(turbidity) <- turbidity$Sample
```

The dots on your biplot will then be labelled with their cognate sample name.

Comment: NB you'll want to use a code formatting block (4 spaces) for nicer looks than a quote block (`> `)

Comment: Hi Manuel, Thanks for your answer. I am able to get the row.names variable to compute but this does not change the biplot labels. I have tried inserting it into the various codes but can't get it to alter anything on the plot. Does this need to be inserted elsewhere or with extra code?

Answer (score 0):

I try with an example:

```
#creating an example data frame with 5 numeric and one character variables
mydata1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100, 0, 2), ncol = 5))
mydata1$sample <- c(sapply(1:20, function(i) paste("s", i, sep = "")))
#view of the df
 mydata1
       V1         V2           V3          V4          V5 sample
1   1.7398057 -0.8074246  0.009826488  0.58566480  3.88569625     s1
2  -1.3259889 -2.4359229 -1.258855445  2.65124987 -2.64137545     s2
3  -2.3961068 -0.3108402 -1.330362255 -0.35209302 -2.39282594     s3
```

This is a 20 rows by 6 variables dataframe

```
biplot(prcomp(mydata1[,-6]))
```

This statement will return a plot without the sample label, only numbers.

```
#naming rows of the df with the sample column value
row.names(mydata1) <- mydata1$sample
#viewing the df 
head(mydata1)
      V1         V2           V3         V4         V5 sample
s1  1.739806 -0.8074246  0.009826488  0.5856648  3.8856962     s1
s2 -1.325989 -2.4359229 -1.258855445  2.6512499 -2.6413755     s2
s3 -2.396107 -0.3108402 -1.330362255 -0.3520930 -2.3928259     s3
#plotting
biplot(prcomp(mydata1[,-6]))
```

The latter plot will now render the observations with their labels. 
Let me know if that is what you had in mind.

Comment: An alternative of prcomp() for issuing good looking score and loading plots from pca is offered by the FactoMineR and factoextra packages.

Comment: Hi Manuel, Thanks for the addition. this is what I had in mind but its the code: 'row.names(mydata1) <- mydata1$sample' that is not working. I got the folllowing message. 'Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed In addition: Warning message: non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘’ '

Comment: Ah yes, row names of a dataframe have to be unique.  Some records in the sample column of your turbidity data set must occur more than once (may be reporting replicates).  A quick and dirty solution is to append a unique character to the sample value, something like:   row.names(mydata1) <- sapply(1:dim(mydata1)[1], function(i) paste(i, mydata1$sample[i], sep = ""))    The drawback of that option is that your sample labels will be rendered with a trailing digit.

Comment: Thanks very much. Following your comment I revisited my data and figures a way of labelling them. Thanks very much for all your help. Very much appreciated. Do you know how to alter the arrow colours in the biplot by any chance?

Comment: yes indeed,  pass 2 color values to the col argument, e.g.    biplot(prcomp(mydata1[,-6]), col = c("red", "yellow"))    I'll let you pick the colors !

Comment: Thanks very much - that's great! Apologies for all the questions I am relatively new to ordination techniques in r! Can you add symbols onto the plot as well as the labels?